# Including parameter expression

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm new in Informatica PowerCenter, trying to use a new declared parameter expression in Workflow Session parameter file.

Objective: the expression is being feed automatically from data base, so the reason behind all this is to be able to change the logic in db, parameter file will re-generate in the next run with the new logic which ultimately will cause not to change nothing in power Center, only record expression in db. Off course for new fields you will need to change informatica.

Let me summarize or try to be deatailed as posible.

Parameter file has no issues, when executing the workflow it's being read with out issues, here's an example of the parameter expression I'm trying to use (rest of them, dbCon, time etc i delete them)

```
[Example.WF:Example.WT:.ST:Example]
$$Param_checker=IIF(1=1,'A','B')
```

Mapping

Created the parameter in the mapping as:

- Name: $$Param_checker
- Type: Parameter
- Data Type: String (as per doc)
- Precision: 10000 <-- making sure there's no cut
- IsExprVar: true

Created a field in a Transformation Expression Box (the violet one) as:

- Name: out_param_checker
- Data Type: String
- Precision: 10
- O: X
- Expresion: $$Param_checker

Workflow

In it session reads correctly the parameter file of the Mapping replaces all variables but when it comes to $$Param_checker it's not being expanded, this is a sample of log outcome when inserting on data base (cast and allfunctions are done by Inf. aut.:

```
CASE WHEN CAST('$$Param_checker' AS VARCHAR(4000))
```

And off course in Data base when process finishes I see the string as well '$$Param_checker'

Just in case, and sorry for being verbose, I do already have a parameter with a expression working but in a source Qualifier using it on a SQL statement.

The issue is why can't I use it in a out field. Forgot to mention that we have redshift under the hood, all sessions are set to "Full" Optimization, hence I think that's the issue.

If anyone have any hint would appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: your requirement is unclear. But, can you use `$$Param_checker` without quotes in expression transformation? Also, this $$Param_checker looks like informatica expression, may not work in SQ.

Comment: Hi Koushik, thanks for your replay. By all means ask all necessary questions.

$$Param_checker expression does not have single quotes, this last ones are being added by Informatica as it treats the expression as an string.

Also if you mean Source Qualifier by "SQ", $$Param_checker is not used in such box, is used in the violet expression box (once again sry still learning boxes names) on the mapping and is being used as an expression.

Comment: normally they are used as a parameter value and not like informatica condition. So, if i were you, i would pass values in param file ( like 'A','B','X') and then write IIF clause in informatica expression(violet color widget).

Comment: Koushik added objective paragraph to explain why I want this, But basically I store power  center expression logic for the field in data base. On workflow execution parameter file re-generates taking input from db and felling all params. If any requirements comes up with change of logic on any field I can change db and that's it with out changing nothing in power center.

basically would like to know if it's posible when you have enables push down, cause parameter keeps as string and not expanding. :(

Comment: `will they expand and behave` -thats what i am skeptical about. parameters are considered as whole string and not a command so parameters wont act like a command. I have not seen it. You can create a program /maplet to translate DB stored values to IIF clause but that can have scalability problem.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers ! will try to book a review in the next 6 months to see if there's any update or diff approach.

Comment: I found a solution for your problem. You need to set IsExprVar-true.

Comment: https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/designer-guide/mapping-parameters-and-variables/defining-expression-strings-in-parameter-files.html

Comment: I can see you followed above link but see if you followed it correctly. Also check if this runs without push down optimization.

Comment: Hi Koushik, isVarExp was set to true. Also can not use without push down optimization  as I have several other variables that would need to change while loosing performance. There fore can not tern off PDO :(